# stuck on login screen after Kubuntu 19 -> 20 upgrade

Tags: upgrade, kubuntu, login, 20.04, do-release-upgrade

I feel a bit sheepish asking such a silly question, but how does one login in the new Kubuntu 20 login screen? Pressing Enter after typing my password does nothing, and I don't see any button to press for login.

For a bit more context, I got here by running the unnatended upgrade logged into Kubuntu 19 session. The first reboot failed so I got to a command line and repaired the upgrade using apt. Reboot again, and now I'm here.

I apologise if this has been asked before. Searching for an answer has been difficult on the mobile, and they all seemed to be from older versions.

Comment: Hm..., last time I've checked, the `unattended-upgrade` thing only installed updates. To upgrade, you needed to run `do-release-upgrade` or the Update Manager. So, have you upgraded from 19? to 20.04? How?

Comment: That is what I meant, sorry. I was using the same language that said "unattended upgrade in progress, please do not shut off your computer" or something like that. Please feel free to edit the language in my post.

Comment: I am going to try and login to shell and manually launch xserver. Maybe this will shine a light on the problem.

Comment: Yeah I think maybe xserver is broken, if that is even still a thing. startx yielded a blank (blackish) screen. I am somewhere in-between power user and novice admin, so any suggestions will be greatly appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: Alright so it looks like my apt repair job didn't take since I needed to manually connect to WiFi first. It's moving along now. I will post back with the results.

Answer (score 0):

If anything goes wrong during a release upgrade, one can repair it by hitting the `CTRL+ALT+FN3` keys and logging into a command line shell. First ensure you are connected to the internet with `ip -a`, then proceeded with the upgrade using standard apt commands. EG `apt update` and `apt upgrade`. This may fail at first. Just follow any directions given in the error message and keep going until you are back to your desktop.

I hope this will save someone some time in the future.